# Is there a nice way to have different configurations for different environments?

Tags: dart

I've created an app that requires some configuration.  The way I'm doing it now is a bit hacky and tedious -- If I'm developing locally, I include the "local" configuration file (a dart file that defines a few consts) and if deploying, I include a different dart file that defines the same consts with different values.

Ideally, there would be a way to define different configurations, which could be passed to pub serve/build.  It seems like such an obvious need that I feel like something may already exist and I just haven't run across it yet.  Is there?  Or is something in the works?

Comment: I answered a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519574 and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338688 ;-)
See also Greg Lowes answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288002

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pub build does not support defining environment variables](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15806)  but you can use [`fromEnvironment` method](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-core.String#id_String-fromEnvironment), for example, on `String`:

```dart
String.fromEnvironment(String name, {String defaultValue})
```

> Returns the string value of the environment declaration name.
>   Environment declarations are provided by the surrounding system
>   compiling or running the Dart program. Declarations map a string key
>   to a string value.

Or make it "fancier" with [transformers](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/assets-and-transformers.html). It will allow you to automatically(on pub build or pub serve) get settings from `pubspec.yaml` or another source and embed them in to the code. For example [sass](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sass)(it is transformer) package supports settings of this form:

```dart
:::yaml
transformers:
  - sass:
      executable: /path/to/sass     # Sass executable to use
      compass: true                 # Include compass
      line-numbers: true            # Include line numbers in output
      style: compact                # Style of generated CSS
      copy-sources: true            # Copy original .scss/.sass files to output directory
```

With it you can do pretty much anything including source code modification.