# Filter Dart files during dart2js process launch by 'pub build' command

Tags: dart, dart2js

is it possible to filter dart files during 'pub build  => dart2js' ?

I'm working with a microservice architecture where I need to specify a variable in the code according to the environement type ( integration vs production).

The common use case is to specify the server url

Comment: Some similar questions, not sure what you exactly try to accomplish
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482536/is-there-a-nice-way-to-have-different-configurations-for-different-environments/24483485#24483485, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519574/dart-how-to-use-different-settings-in-debug-and-production-mode, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338688/how-to-achieve-precompiler-directive-like-functionality, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288002/is-there-a-compiler-preprocessor-in-dart

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looking for [`transformers` option in `pubspec.yml`](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec.html).

See what transformers can do: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/assets-and-transformers.html

How to write a custom transformer: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/transformers/index.html