# How do I handle post requests from my dart app ran from the dart editor?

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-pub

I have code that looks something like this (`_http` is the angular Http object)

```dart
    var httpFuture = _http.post('/api/items', {
      'ids': JSON.encode(new List.from(nonLoadedIds))
    });
    httpFuture.catchError((e) {
      Logger.root.severe('Unable to load items!', e);
    });
```

It is making a post request to load a bunch of things.  Potentially more ids than the http get header can handle.

The nice development experience would be if I could fire up the dart editor, mock up some fake response data, run my app, and see the data in the end.  I would also accept being able to start up a separate web app and somehow proxy my post requests to that web app.

What I don't want to do is change my `'/api/items'` into something like `'http://localhost:8084/api/items'` mostly because I don't want to have to remember to replace these before deploying (I know I'll forget) and while doable, I don't want to on my server implement CORS just to have to remember to disable it when I deploy to production.

But really, I would accept just about any workflow if it is recommended.  I just would like to eliminate any manual code transformations pre production deploy.

Comment: After poking around on the IRC channels, my current solution is to use a const debugging boolean and remembering to set it to 'false' before I do my build.  Everywhere I need to hit the server, I'm doing this `const url = DEBUGGING ? '${HOST}/api/items' : '/api/items';`  I'm not entirely satisfied by  this solution, but it is there if someone else wants it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggested attempt is to use a simple proxy server which forwards to `pub serve`.

See for example https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=18039
This issue contains the source code for a simple custom proxy server example https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15731

see also

- [Dart: How to use different settings in debug and production mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519574)
- [How to achieve precompiler directive like functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338688)
- [Is there a compiler preprocessor in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288002)