# Detect during runtime whether the application is in release mode or not

Tags: build, dart

I got a bunch of tests and debug stuff in my Dart application and I would like to make sure these kind of things are disabled when I build a release version with pub.

Is there any constant or some other way to check if the current running version of the application is a release build or not?

Example:

```
if (!IS_BUILD) {
   performAutomatedDummyLogin()
} else {
   login();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Code in `assert(...);` is only executed in checked (development) mode. When you run in release mode or build in release mode this code isn't executed.

```
bool isRelease = true;
assert(() {
  isRelease = false;
  return true;
});

if(isRelease) {
 ...
}
```

see also

- [Dart: How to use different settings in debug and production mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519574)
- [How to achieve precompiler directive like functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338688)
- [Is there a compiler preprocessor in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288002)

Comment: If you change the boolean to be `isChecked`, you can make it shorter: `bool isChecked = false; assert((isChecked = true));`. But then, you can still avoid the extra function syntax for `isRelease` by doing `assert(!(isRelease = false))`;

Comment: Right, I tried to make it obvious that the expression needs to return `true`.

Comment: Pedagogical reasons is an excellent argument, so take my comment as extra hints for those of us to like to optimization for size :)