# Dart const as preprocessor directives

Tags: flutter, dart

I was looking for something similar to preprocessor directives in Dart.

The idea is to avoid the compiling of certain portions of code conditionally to some flags.

Now, reading stuff like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288002/is-there-a-compiler-preprocessor-in-dart) I came to think that when the Dart compiler performs the Tree shaking it will throw away unused parts of code, excluding them from the compiled code.

Assuming I got this right, would something like this:

```
static const needExecute = false;

if (needExecute){
  //instructions
}
```

or like this:

```
static const needValue = false;

var myList = [
        "value1", 
        if(needValue) 
          "value2", 
        if(needValue) 
          "value3",
        ]
```

The compiler should know at compile time that that code will never be executed and it would fall "victim" of the tree shaking, not being compiled at all.

Moreover, would [conditional imports](https://medium.com/@dvargahali/dart-2-conditional-imports-update-16147a776aa8) be an acceptable way of doing things too?

I mean, could I use two different imports exposing a method which would be empty or contain the instructions (first case) or the two kinds of lists (second case).

Is there any way I can know this for sure, assuming I do not have the skills for decompiling an app?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've written ad article about this integrating Rémi's answer. You can learn more about this topic here: https://medium.com/flutter-community/excluding-dart-code-from-the-release-compiled-executable-7af8c18cd241

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your assumption is right. If the evaluation of an `if` can be evaluated at compile-time, it will be tree-shaked accordingly.

As such, writing:

```dart
const condition = true;

if (condition) {
  print('42');
} else {
  print('24');
}
```

will compile to:

```dart
print('42');
```

The `if` being removed because it was evaluated at compilation already. No need to re-evaluate it at runtime

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answering, this is so helpful! Following this assumption the removal of the `if` will also affect the second case, where it is used inside a collection, right?

Comment: Great. Thank you very much!